# #python products #barcode_recognition /saving results to Excel file

Tags: python, opencv, barcode, image-recognition

I'm stuck with my "little" project barcode recognition. I'm new in python and in all of the programming stuff. 
So I borrowed half of this code from internet and now I am trying adapting it to my needs.
Basicly what it should do:

1. scan through all images in folder for barcode numbers.
2. save the images name and barcode number to Excel file.

Sounds simple, but not for me.. I'm stuck about a week now, looking for all kind's of tutorials and in this site, till I decided to register in here to ask this ONE solution OR some guidance, where I am doing it wrong. So this is the code and my expectations when I'm adding results to a list. (none,none,none.. )
P.S. I'm using python 3.6, windows 7 (sometimes 10, don't ask why.. )

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import os
import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

folder = "C:\\Users\\dava8001\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-        32\\bar-code-project\\2018-08-07_Eurovaitine,Salma\\"
barcode = []

def decode(im) : 
  # Find barcodes and QR codes
  decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(im)

  # Print results
  for obj in decodedObjects:

    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder, f))]
    print('Type : ', obj.type)
    code = print('Number : ', obj.data,'\n')
    barcode.append(code)

  return decodedObjects

# Display barcode and QR code location  
def display(im, decodedObjects):

  # Loop over all decoded objects
  for decodedObject in decodedObjects: 
    points = decodedObject.polygon

    # If the points do not form a quad, find convex hull
    if len(points) > 4 : 
      hull = cv2.convexHull(np.array([point for point in points],         dtype=np.float32))
      hull = list(map(tuple, np.squeeze(hull)))
    else : 
      hull = points;

    # Number of points in the convex hull
    n = len(hull)

    # Draw the convext hull
    for j in range(0,n):
      cv2.line(im, hull[j], hull[ (j+1) % n], (255,0,0), 3)

  # Display results 
  #cv2.imshow("Results", im);
  #cv2.waitKey(0);


# Main 
if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Read image
  #im = [i for i in glob.glob(folder + "*.jpg") if isfile(join(folder, i))]
  for img in glob.glob(folder + "*.jpg"):
      im = cv2.imread(img)

      decodedObjects = decode(im)
      display(im, decodedObjects)

#print(barcode)
```

And my outup is like this..

> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'9000100960342'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'9000100961172'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'5060283070508'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'5201279037109'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'5201279037109'
>
> Type :  CODE128
>       Number :  b'1000002125861'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'3574660244182'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4026600682800'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'3282770104783'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'7070866024680'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'7070866024680'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'5903104370008'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'5902114231880'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'2355106901552'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4770511211030'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4770577797066'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4170511791066'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4770511191066'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4170511197066'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'5060195750451'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4771138392669'
>
> Type :  EAN13
>       Number :  b'4771138392669'

```
 ###print(barcode)###
 >>> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,        None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Thant you!

Comment: If you are using Python3, do don't need to import `print_function`. Python3 _is_ the future.

Comment: Thank you, you're right! P.S. I've just fixed few lines: made onlyfiles variable global, wrote try: and except: condition and this ###im = {}
    
    try:
      barcode.append(int(obj.data))
    except Exception as e:
      print(str(e))### ! Now it's addint barcodes to a list!